# Invoke method/Do action before every POST/GET request .NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net, post, asp.net-core, middleware

**What I am trying to achieve** - My application is simply ASP .Net Core application. **It is not Web API.** I want to execute method before every post/get request from my app to external sources, for example:
I am sending a post request, to check SSL expiry date to some website API and it returns me a response. According to the response I am sending another request or not. I don't want to place call method statement before every request, I would like to do it globally.

I was trying to achieve this based on http://www.sulhome.com/blog/10/log-asp-net-core-request-and-response-using-middleware

As it occurs, this middleware works(I have it working) only for internal requests(routing requests inside application).

Is there any possibility to do it for all requests?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6):

.NET Core allows to create custom middlewares to get into MV pipeline. Here is an example:

```
public class MyMiddleware
    {
        private readonly RequestDelegate _next;


        public MyMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
        {
            _next = next;
        }

        public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
        {
            //do your checkings
            await _next(context);
        }
}
```

In Startup.cs in Config method just regiester it:

```
app.UseMiddleware<MyMiddleware>(Options.Create(options));
```

Comment: I have done everything as you said, but it hits this Task Invoke only when request is going **from** my application **to** my application. What I want to achieve is that Invoke() is executed in situation like this:
After action in my controller, 'in next method', the request is send to external website. And before sending this request I would like to execute Invoke(). So
1. Post request going to my app.
2. Some methods are executed - in controller and in other classes
3.Invoke() is executed - in this task request with checking SSL is sent
4.According to response other actions are executed

Comment: Maybe you have to add Middleware at the end of pipeline in config?

Comment: From my understanding (and correct me if I'm wrong) he wants to capture outgoing requests, not incoming requests

Comment: Carlos G is right. That's exactly what I am talking about

Answer (score 0):

Since you are talking about doing a call on Outgoing requests, you have two mechanisms to solve the problem:

1. Use an Aspect Oriented Programming Library (like https://www.postsharp.net)
2. Implement your own Request class (that has the global behavior you desire) and make sure that all requests are done using this class (or a class that inherits from it).

For the second point, a good mechanism is that the base class provides a `SendRequest` method that receives an `HttpRequestMessage` and executes the global code. Classes that inherit from it use this method to send the requests and have no access to the underlying `HttpClient` (so that they cannot run around the `SendRequest` method).